# How to add flip switch at right side of header using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I wanna add flip switch at right side of header using jquery mobile. I tried this but it goes to next line.

```html
<div data-role="header" >
  <a href="#main-panel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars" ></a>
  <h1>Flowers</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch"  data-role="flipswitch" data-on-text="True" data-off-text="False">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to place your flipswitch inside of a "control-group" element.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-btn-right">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-based-flipswitch"  data-role="flipswitch" data-on-text="True" data-off-text="False">
</fieldset>
```